# How to HIDE and SHOW answer?

Tags: exam

I want to make a handout, which contains a lot of questions.

I want a output of this:

[image]

Another output is like this:

[image]

The 3rd output is like this:

1. Calculate 1+2
2. Calculate 1+2+3
3. Calculate 1+2+3+4
4. Calculate 1+2+3+4+5
5. Calculate 1+2+3+4+5+6

The problem here is just my example, I have thousands of middle school examination questions. Who can teach me to use only one TEX file output of three kinds of PDF files, thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a code sampler (MWE) that shows what you've got.

Comment: Btw: Are you really using `LaTeX 2.09` as your tag suggests? Is it necessary for the answer to be outdated `LaTeX 2.09` or may it be up-to-date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what erik said, I've found that for many classes I wanted the text of all the questions followed by each question with space to fill. I've extended the exam class to do this automatically, with just typing the questions once and a couple of passes of the compiler.

```
%\NeedsTeXFormat{Latex2e}[1996/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{examExt}[2016/11/09 v1.0]

\LoadClassWithOptions{exam}
\RequirePackage{etex}

\global\newwrite\examfile%

\newcommand\insertQuestions[1][plain]{
\begingroup
\IfFileExists{./\jobname.exm}{\thispagestyle{#1}\input{\jobname.exm}}{\typeout{Class exam Warning: Questions file created. Rerun to get expected output.}}
\endgroup
\immediate\openout\examfile=\jobname.exm
}



\AtEndDocument{
\immediate\closeout\examfile
}

\newcommand\create@environment[1]{
\newenvironment{my#1}{%
\begin{#1}
\immediate\write\examfile{\string\begin{#1}}
}{%
\immediate\write\examfile{\string\end{#1}}
\end{#1}
}
}



\newcommand\create@item[1]{
\expandafter\newcommand\csname my#1\endcsname[2]{%
\if\relax\detokenize{##1}\relax
\csname #1\endcsname ##2
\immediate\write\examfile{\string\csname \space #1\string\endcsname\relax \unexpanded{##2}}%
\else
 \csname #1\endcsname[##1] ##2
\immediate\write\examfile{\string\csname \space #1\string\endcsname[##1] \unexpanded{##2}}%
\fi
}
}

\newcommand\create@titleditem[1]{
\expandafter\newcommand\csname my#1\endcsname[3]{%
\if\relax\detokenize{##2}\relax
\csname #1\endcsname{##1} ##3
\immediate\write\examfile{\string\csname \space #1\string\endcsname\unexpanded{\begingroup ##1\endgroup}\relax \unexpanded{##3}}%
\else
 \csname #1\endcsname{##1}[##2] ##3
\immediate\write\examfile{\string\csname \space #1\string\endcsname\unexpanded{##1}[##2] \unexpanded{##3}}%
\fi
}
}

\create@environment{questions}
\create@environment{parts}
\create@environment{subparts}
\create@environment{subsubparts}
\create@item{question}
\create@item{part}
\create@item{subpart}
\create@item{subsubpart}
\create@titleditem{titledquestion}
\newcommand\insertClearPage{\immediate\write\examfile{\string\clearpage}}
```

Here's a MWE showing how to use it. It will create another file and on a second pass, copy the questions on the top.

```
\documentclass{examExt}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

 \insertQuestions
 \clearpage
 \begin{myquestions}
  \myquestion{2}{This is a question $3\in\mathbb{R}$}


  \begin{solutionbox}{3in}
   This is a solution
  \end{solutionbox}

  \begin{myparts}
   \mypart{2}{This is a part}


   \begin{solutionbox}{3in}
   This is a solution
  \end{solutionbox}
  \end{myparts}
 \end{myquestions}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Here I introduce `\Calculate{}` to provide the problem, and `\Solution{}` to provide the answer.  Note that `\Solution` automatically restates the "problem" as the first line, and the optional argument of `[]` suppresses the line feed that normally would follow (shown in item 1).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,enumitem}
\newcommand\Calculate[1]{Calculate $#1$\def\Question{#1}}
\newcommand\Solution[2][\\]{Solution: \Longunderstack[l]{\Question#1#2}}
\stackMath
% TO PROVIDE BLANK SOLUTION
%\renewcommand\Solution[2][\\]{Solution: \setbox0=\hbox{%
%  \Longunderstack[l]{\Question#1#2}}\rule[-\dp0]{0pt}{\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0}}
% TO PROVIDE NO SOLUTION
%\renewcommand\Solution[2][\\]{}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{enumerate}[listparindent=0in,itemsep=5pt]
\item \Calculate{1 + 2}

  \Solution[]{=3}

\item \Calculate{1 + 2 + 3}

  \Solution{=3+3\\=6}

\item \Calculate{1+2+3+4}

  \Solution{=3+3+4\\=6+4\\=10}

\item \Calculate{1+2+3+4+5}

  \Solution{=3+3+4+5\\=6+4+5\\=10+5\\=15}

\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To get the solutions blanked out, just uncomment the lines to redefine `\Solution` as

```
\renewcommand\Solution[2][\\]{Solution: \setbox0=\hbox{%
  \Longunderstack[l]{\Question#1#2}}\rule[-\dp0]{0pt}{\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0}}
```

[image]

To get **no** solution, just uncomment the other line to redefine `\Solution` as

```
\renewcommand\Solution[2][\\]{}
```

[image]

---

**ALTERNATE**

If you would like to not have to type the `=` at the beginning of each line of the solution, that can be achieved but only by giving up the optional argument capability of suppressing the line feed after the problem restatement (compare item 1).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,enumitem}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\newcommand\Calculate[1]{Calculate $#1$\def\Question{#1}}
\newcommand\Solution[1]{Solution: \stackunder{\Question}
  {\tabbedLongunderstack[l]{#1}}}
\stackMath
\TABstackMath
\TABstackMathstyle{=}
% TO PROVIDE BLANK SOLUTION
%\renewcommand\Solution[1]{Solution: \setbox0=\hbox{\stackunder{\Question}%
%  {\tabbedLongunderstack[l]{#1}}}\rule[-\dp0]{0pt}{\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0}}
% TO PROVIDE NO SOLUTION
%\renewcommand\Solution[1]{}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{enumerate}[listparindent=0in,itemsep=5pt]
\item \Calculate{1 + 2}

  \Solution{3}

\item \Calculate{1 + 2 + 3}

  \Solution{3+3\\6}

\item \Calculate{1+2+3+4}

  \Solution{3+3+4\\6+4\\10}

\item \Calculate{1+2+3+4+5}

  \Solution{3+3+4+5\\6+4+5\\10+5\\15}

\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `exam` class, which would also allow you to leave space for the solution. It also allows you to assign points to questions or parts of questions (which I omit here).

```
\documentclass[
answers
]{exam}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question Calculate \(1 + 2\)
\begin{solution}
\(1 + 2 = 3\)
\end{solution}

\question Calculate \(1 + 2 + 3\)
\begin{solution}
\begin{align*}
& 1 + 2 + 3\\
& = 3 + 3\\
& = 6
\end{align*}
\end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]